# SwiftUI Charts BarMark Foreground Style Color Based on Fixed Values

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts

I'm trying to format the color of a BarMark in SwiftUI Charts where the color is
determined by a fixed value definition. Say there is a data element with a high of 162 and
a low of -10. I want the bar color from any negative number to 0 to be blue, from 0 to 35
to be green, from 35 to 70 to be yellow, from 70 to 105 to be orange and anything
over 105 to be red.

This is how I want it to look.

[image]

I achieved this by creating 5 records and listing the
high and low for each segment. My input data will only give me the bar high and low i.e.
162 and -10 in this example. I tried to create an IF structure to calculate the high
and low values from the given data, but it quickly becomes a nightmare once you take
into account that the data high and low could be anything as long as high >= low.

Here's the code for the above view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var yValues: [Int] {
        stride(from: -35, to: 210, by: 35).map { $0 }
    }

    let stackColors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Chart(revenueDataRule) { item in
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Period", item.period),
                        //y: .value("Amount", item.amount)
                        yStart: .value("High", item.high),
                        yEnd: .value("Low", item.low),
                        width: 20
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Department", item.band))
            }//chart
            .frame(height: 500)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: yValues)
            }
            .frame(height: 500)
            .chartForegroundStyleScale(
                domain: revenueDataRule.compactMap( {revenue in revenue.band} ),
                range: stackColors
            )//scale
        }//v
    }//body

    let revenueDataRule: [RevenueRule] = [
        RevenueRule(period: "2022 Q1", band: "Sales", high: 162, low: 105),
        RevenueRule(period: "2022 Q1", band: "IT", high: 105, low: 70),
        RevenueRule(period: "2022 Q1", band: "Finance", high: 70, low: 35),
        RevenueRule(period: "2022 Q1", band: "CEO", high: 35, low: 1),
        RevenueRule(period: "2022 Q1", band: "Intern", high: 0, low: -10)
        ]
}

struct RevenueRule: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let period: String
    let band: String
    let high: Double
    let low: Double
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated: Xcode 14.2 iOS 16.2

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have managed to figure it out by now! However, here's the answer for the future me, in case I search for it .

```
.chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: yValues)
            }
```

So basically instead of passing the `yValues` to the `AxisMarks`, you need to just to tell the `AxisMark` that you want to customise the scale a bit like so

```
.chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .automatic(minimumStride: 0, desiredCount: yValues.count * 4, roundLowerBound: true, roundUpperBound: true))
            }
```

Or simply

```
.chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: 5))
            }
```

[image: The new result]

You could also customise the YAxis labels to show the numbers you want and ignore the rest, if you want to; like this

```
.chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic(minimumStride: 0, desiredCount: yValues.count * 4, roundLowerBound: true, roundUpperBound: true))
            { value in
                let doubleValue: Double = value.as(Double.self) ?? 1
                if doubleValue.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2) != 0 {
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel {
                        Text("\(Int(doubleValue))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You could also simplify that, with

```
.chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: 5))
                { value in
                    let doubleValue: Double = value.as(Double.self) ?? 1
                    if doubleValue.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2) != 0 {
                        AxisGridLine()
                        AxisValueLabel {
                            Text("\(Int(doubleValue))")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: The final result]

Comment: Ofcourse - Thanks for the note. My issue was not the axis values but rather the color coding of a bar where I did not know the band numbers a priory. I got pretty close using the built in modifier .alignsMarkStylesWithPlotArea(true). Check it out.

Comment: Well,  depends on your question, my solution should do the trick. However, I'll be interested in the final solution, please do post it, when you figure it out.